# Laravel Scope Search a related model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a **Travel** model that references a **Country** model. I am trying to get list of travel history that has matching country name to the search input via laravel's ***scopeSearch***.

Below is what I've tried so far:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search='')
{
        return $query->orderBy("arrival_date", "desc")
                    ->with(['country' => function ($query) use($search){
                        $query->WhereRaw("name LIKE ? ", '%' . $search . '%');
                    }])
                    ->WhereRaw("destination LIKE ? ", '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhereRaw("city LIKE ? ", '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->whereNull("delete_date");
}
```

But I am getting empty results. Below is the method that references country model

```
public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
```

Edit: After using `toSql()`as suggested I'm getting below query

```
select * from `travel_schedule` where `travel_schedule`.`user_id` = ? and `travel_schedule`.`user_id` is not null and (destination LIKE ?  or city LIKE ?  and `delete_date` is null) order by `arrival_date` desc
```

Further Edit: Solved it myself thanks to the answer from Marcin Nabiałek. I am posting the code below in case it helps any user that is trying to solve a similar problem

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search='')
{

        return $query->WhereRaw("destination LIKE ? ", '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhereRaw("city LIKE ? ", '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('country', function ($query) use($search){
                    $query->WhereRaw("name LIKE ? ", '%'.$search.'%');
                })
                ->whereNull("delete_date");
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `get` or `first` to get your results, use `toSql()` and show us the output.

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: you must be avoid use directly user input in sql command `name LIKE ? ", '%'.$search.'%'`. It must be vulnerable in `sql injection`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you don't search here anything, you use here `with` and I believe you want to use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead.

Your scope should look like this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search='')
{
    return $query->orderBy("arrival_date", "desc")
                ->whereHas('country', function ($query) use($search){
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE' '%' . $search . '%');
                })
                ->whereNull("delete_date");
}
```

I would also avoid using `orderBy` in such scope in case you wanted to sort results in different way

Comment: I am getting `Class App\Travel does not exist` error

Comment: Well, I don't know in what file you have Travel model and in which namespace. If it's in app/Travel.php file, you put `namespace App;` on top of file and class has name Travel then `App\Travel` should work